# Powershell: Why is recurse not working?

Tags: powershell

Hi I have a script that should ideally copy an item and paste it onto a destination folder including all of it's sub folders. However I cannot get it to copy the item into the subfolders.

Here is the code:

```
Copy-Item "\\postowl\PEC Group\HR\Performance snapshot\Performance Snapshot Macro.xlsm" -Destination "\\postowl\PEC Group\HR\Performance snapshot\2017-2018" -Recurse -Force
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Recurse` copies the subfolders and item from the source to the destination, preserving directory structure. It doesn't recurse in the destination and make multiple copies in the destination. You could use a `ForEach-Object` loop from the output of `Get-ChildItem` where you retrieve all of the folders you wish to copy to.

```
Get-ChildItem "\\postowl\PEC Group\HR\Performance snapshot\2017-2018" -Directory -Recurse | % {
Copy-Item "\\postowl\PEC Group\HR\Performance snapshot\Performance Snapshot Macro.xlsm" -Destination $_.fullname -Force }
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. But it didn't work unfortunately. Don't you need to specify "ForEach" somewhere in the syntax?

Comment: `%` is the alias for `ForEach-Object`. I forgot to include `.Fullname` after `$_`. The answer has been edited with the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Two things from my observation.

1)You are telling you are copying an item including its sub-folders, but in the source you have mentioned one file name with extension. not sure if thats the folder name in your case.

2) I found that in the destination you are not going inside the final level folder.

So put this and check:

```
Copy-Item "\\postowl\PEC Group\HR\Performance snapshot\*.xlsm" -Destination "\\postowl\PEC Group\HR\Performance snapshot\2017-2018\" -Recurse -Force
```

Note: If its a specific file, then you can remove the wildcard because that will copy all the files with the extension .xlsm . I have kept it because I am assuming you have only one file under that folder.

See the Documentation and the issue with PS:
[Copy-Item Nature & Issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.windows.powershell/rpuLRCTCryI)